# DateTime or int to string inside IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

How do I convert DateTime or int to string inside IQueryable? I need to do something like this, but without `ToString()`, which throws `System.NotSupportedException` exception:

```
IQueryable filteredEntities = myIQueryableCollection
    .Where(o => o.SomeDateTime.ToString().Contains(searchParameter) 
        || o.SomeInt.ToString().Contains(searchParameter));
```

For double and decimal I use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` functions, but there are no overloads for int or DateTime.

Please note that I absolutely need deferred execution there. Calling `ToList()` is not an option with the amount of data that I am working with.

Comment: Your search condition `o.SomeDateTime.ToString().Contains(searchParameter)` doesn't make much sense to me. Wouldn't it be more convenient to search based on time interval using some `from` and `to` dates? Then you would be able to compare dates, not strings.

Comment: The problem is that I need to have a single search field that filters all properties. But this is a good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: EF 6.1 supports ToString method: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **SqlFunctions.DateName**:

```
data.Where(o => SqlFunctions.DateName("year", o.SomeDateTime).Contains(searchParameter) ||
                SqlFunctions.DateName("month", o.SomeDateTime).Contains(searchParameter) ||
                SqlFunctions.DateName("weekday", o.SomeDateTime).Contains(searchParameter))
```

There may be a need to search for other data other than 'year' / 'month' / 'weekday', depending on what would `searchParameter` look like.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487164%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This is very good suggestion! Thanks. "month" datepart returns month name instead of numeric result, but I will figure something out :)

Comment: Ignore my last sentence. I just found that there is also SqlFunctions.DatePart function that returns a numeric value

Comment: Since you're performing `Contains` on the string, i was pretty sure it's the textual representation you're interested in...

Comment: That makes sense. Anyway, if not your answer, I would not have found DatePart

Comment: @SoftwareFactor I would love to see the translated SQL using this approach with the DatePart in place.

Answer (score -3):

MSDN seems to suggest using the following extension method:

```
Enumerable.Cast<TResult>
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).ASPX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

Comment: I don't think this helps here: He does not have an `IEnumerable` as he wants to convert one property of each object in his collection and `IEnumerable` would also trigger the `IQueryable` to be executed against the DB.